# Build OpenCV for VS 2015

Tags: opencv, build, visual-studio-2015

I want to build **OpenCV** with the **CUDA**-module and **contrib** for Visual Studio 2015. It works for VS 2013, but, as far as I have heard, there were some problems building it for the 2015 version at the beginning of this year.

Is this solved / what would not work?

Comment: Why don't you figure out that by yourself?

Comment: I hope that there is someone having experience with this before I get errors when coding and starting debugging for hours until I figure out that it is because I do use VS2015 in contrast to all other tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved know (it did not work in August). See the [documentation for OpenCV 3.2](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html).